# Explicit type casting vs using suffix for float/double Java - difference?

Tags: java

Based on the snippet below:

```
    // as primitive
    MyClass.primitiveMethod(double val); // method signature
    MyClass.primitiveMethod(12);         // ok

    // as object
    MyClass.objectMethod(Double val); // method signature
    MyClass.objectMethod(12);         // error
    MyClass.objectMethod(12d);        // ok
    MyClass.objectMethod((double)12); //ok
```

Q1: While both `12d` and `(double)12` seem to work, are there any difference between specifying suffix and explicit casting? (behaviour/performance)

Q2: Why `MyClass.objectMethod(12)` must be considered an error? While 12 is supposed to be resolved to an Integer object, can't Java be smart enough to know that 12 is also a value Double value and just accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question: I'd *expect* the conversion to `double` to be performed by the compiler, but I wouldn't like to say for sure without checking. I'd use the suffix instead, for clarity. (If I need to check, that means anyone maintaining the code would have to check too... why not just use a literal of the right type to start with?)

12 is resolved to an `int`, not an `Integer` - and there's no implicit conversion from `int` to `Double`. Just because there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `double` and another from `double` to `Double` doesn't mean there's one straight there.

It *could* have been included, of course - but it would have meant making the language more complicated for a pretty small level of benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, I never use `12d`.  To make it clear that a number is a double, I use `12.0`. For floats, you have to say `12.0f`.

It's one extra character to type, but I find it by far the most "natural".  YMMV.

ADDED

As to your actual question, autoboxing primitives to and from wrappers can have unexpected results, (a great boon for the Java Puzzlers book!) and I prefer to avoid it as much as possible.  If the method requires a Double, in the calling code I will usually explicitly make it so

```
objectMethod(Double.valueOf(12.0));
```

Although have to admit, that's a lot of typing for something relatively minor!  However, when de-autoboxing (say, the method returns a Double) I almost always say

```
double d = result.doubleValue();
```

and it is *worth it* because it's a reminder that result is an Object and it *might be null*.  When you get some unexplained NPE, say, the method returns null because the FooBarServer is not connected, this will help you realize what is going on.  Or, even better, remind the original code to test for a null result first!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the suffix (literal)
2. It could be, but it seems it isn't. `int` isn't automatically wrapped in a `Double`

But most importantly - prefer primitives to wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

A1: No, they end up both the same after the compiler is done with them.

A2: An `int` primitive is autoboxed to an `Integer` object. See the Java Language Specification, [5.1.7 Boxing Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7).  Would you rather Java guessed at what you meant and changed the Object class for you?  No, it's far better that the programmer tells the machine what to do rather than have the machine guess at the programmer's intentions.

Answer (score 0):

'12d' is a double literal.  '(double) 12' is an operation on an int literal.  You are not guaranteed that the latter will optimize to the former, not that it's likely to make a difference.  The correctly typed literal is cleaner and more self-documenting, so use that.  Why specify an unnecessary conversion?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, use the suffix, *12d* is more brief and clear.

For the second... saying 12 you are using **int**, *primitive* and using **Double** you are speaking about an *object* (a wrapper for **double**) and they are not the same.