# I want to program the iteration of the number e

Tags: java

I'm still a beginner in Java programming, and I'm using Eclipse Neon. How can I make it like that without writing the code again and again? And at the end, I want to print the final number on the screen.

Here's what I did so far:

```
public class othermethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int position = 1;
        int pos = 0;
        int[] zahlenlaenge = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < zahlenlaenge.length; i++) {
            zahlenlaenge[pos] = position;
            position++;
            pos++;
            System.out.println(pos);
        }
    }
}
```

How it should actually work:

[image: e function]

Comment: What are you intending to store in `zahlenlaenge`? Google translate says this means "number follow", but it is not clear to me what that means.

Comment: It should be the numbers below the fraction

Comment: I thought about making an int one = 1; and then divide by the array and multiply like in the example.

Comment: Note that you can't store 100! in an int. Nor can you in a long. As such, you can't store denominator terms in the `zahlenlaenge` array.

Comment: You don't need to define an int one = 1, but you need to store your value in a double, because those fractions aren't going into an int.

Comment: My teacher said i can program this in Java, maybe im all wrong, how would you programm it ? He said I should be able to. Im doing Java for 7 Months now.

Comment: You can program it in Java, but you need to use the correct primitive types to do it.

Comment: I have no idea how to do so....

Comment: Should i just leave it?

Comment: Do you know what a `double` is used for compared to an `int`? That would be a good starting point. After that, figure out how you should track `sum` and `denominator`.

Comment: Yeah i know the types float int double char string. Is the int too small?

Comment: int doesn't store decimal values, if you're trying to calculate the value of e.

Comment: I just wanted to use them to aim to the position of the array, i would save the result in a double but i used the int to get the 1st position and the number saved there for example 1. Like this i wanted to automaticly generate the divide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after evaluating what you're asking, I think your confusion lies in what you're doing with tracking your values.

I've taken most of your code and redone it with doubles, and renamed your array to foo for my typing purposes. I'm not sure what you're tracking, but this provides the discerning of what is sum, what is denominator, and if needed, any other values you can pretty quickly figure out where they come from.

```
    double[] foo = new double[100]; //store the sum at any point in array
    double sum = 1d; //first value
    double denominator = 1d; //first denominator
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
        foo[i] = sum; //set the sum to i (1, 2, 2.5, ...)
        System.out.println(i + ":" foo[i]);
        denominator *= (i + 1); //calculate the next factorial, (1, 2, 3)
        sum += 1d / denominator; //calculate the sum (2, 2.5, ...)
    }
```

You'll notice that this quickly normalizes as the `1d / denominator` becomes super-tiny and is basically ignored for calculations.

Comment: So when you write 1, that's an integer. Depending on how you use it, you may accidentally return what you expect to be a double as an integer. For consistency, anything I expect to be a double is marked as 1d. Anything I expect to be an integer is marked as 1.

Comment: @Javatar sort of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731243/explicit-type-casting-vs-using-suffix-for-float-double-java-difference except it's obviously not a type, but a literal.