# Why does .contains(1) return false when called on a HashSet<Long> that contains 1l?

Tags: java, type-conversion, hashset, autoboxing

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Long> list = Arrays.asList(1l,2l,3l);
    Set<Long> set = new HashSet<>(list);
    System.out.println(set); // [1, 2, 3]
    System.out.println(set.contains(1)); // false
}
```

The `set` contains `{1,2,3}`, but when I call `set.contains(1)` it returns `false`. Why isn't `1` auto casted to `1l`? I think it may be related to Java autoboxing and casting problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731243/explicit-type-casting-vs-using-suffix-for-float-double-java-difference

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Are you familiar with the [diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java)? `Long` is inferred from the variable's declared type `Set<Long>`.

Comment: I was not, but now I am, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments have mentioned that because a long is not an int, the set will not contain it, but I believe there is a more concrete answer that can be given to this case specifically.

If we look into the HashSet source code, we find that its `contains` method falls back to a HashMap's `containsKey` method. Looking into that, we find that the fundamental check is this:

```java
if (e.hash == hash && e.key.equals(key))
```

A simple check will verify that the two values will produce the same hash, but that the direct check below will fail.

```java
new Integer(1).equals(new Long(1l));
```

This happens for the precise reason mentioned in the comments. When you use the Integer (or Long) `equals()` method, the very first thing that Java will do is check if the types are the same. It will *not* do any casting. The types are different, and so the result is false. To avoid this, cast your integer to a long before checking if the set contains it.

Note that this behavior is different from using a primitive-type comparison `1 == 1l`. Java will not wrap these in objects and will not use the object `.equals()` method, so this evaluation is skipped. Casting happens and the result is `true`.

Comment: In other words, `System.out.println(set.contains(1l));` will be true

Answer (score 2):

Because `contains` is defined, for legacy reasons, as `contains(Object)`, not `contains(T)`. The `int` `1`, coerced to an object, is boxed as an `Integer`.